# Illustrate in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ what the open balls of this metric space are

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, d)$ is a metric space, where
$d( (x,y),(x',y') ) =  |y| + |y'| + |x-x'|$ if $x \neq x'$ and  $|y-y'|$ if $x = x'$

Illustrate by diagrams in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ what the open balls of this metric space look like.

I can prove that this is a metric space, and I can draw the part of a ball for x=x'(just a vertical line of radius r), but I am struggling to understand how to draw the rest of the ball for points of different x values.

Comment: **Hint:** What are the possible $y'$ values for a fixed $x'$ with $0<|x-x'|<r-|y|$?

Answer (score 1):

The $r$-ball around $(x,y)$ may come in different shapes, depending on whether a) $y=0$ or b) $r\le |y|>0$, or c) $r>|y|>0$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take some $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$. Then for any positive $r\leq |y|$, the open ball centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $r$ is a vertical segment of length $2r$.

For $r>|y|$, we still get the same segment, but in addition we get a diamond centered at $(x,0)$ with corners at $(x\pm(r-|y|),0)$ and $(x,\pm(r-|y|))$.